on Serre's proof of $L(1,\chi)\neq 0, \forall \chi\neq\chi_0.$
In A Course in Arithmetic, by Serre, he proves the above fact. At the proof, he says "If $L(1,\chi)=0$ for some $\chi\neq\chi_0,$ then $\zeta_m$ would be holomorphic at $s=1,$ and thus holomorphic at $R(s)>0$". My question is: Why it would be holomorphic at $R(s)>0$?
At the previous page, he does the following:
1- prop11: For $\chi =\chi_0,$ we have $$L(s,\chi_0)=\zeta(s) \prod_{p|m} (1-p^{-s}).$$ In particular, $L(s,\chi_0)$ extends analytically for $R(s)>0$ and has a simple pole at $s=1.$
2- prop12: For $\chi\neq\chi_0,$ the series $L(s,\chi)$ converges (resp. converges absolutely) in the half plane $R(s)>0$ (resp. $R(s)>1$) and $$L(s,\chi)=\prod_{p\in P} \dfrac{1}{1-\chi(p)/p^s},$$ where $R(s)>1.$
3- $$\zeta_m(s)=\prod_{\chi\in G(m)} L(s,\chi)=L(s,\chi_0)\prod_{\chi\neq\chi_0\in G(m)} L(s,\chi),$$ where $G(m)=((Z/mZ)^{\times},\cdot).$
I have that question because he proved, for $\chi\neq\chi_0,$ only the convergence at $R(s)>0,$ not that it is holomorphic. I think to prove that fact it must be used other results, but he does it in one phrase, so it must be easier than I thought. Could you help me, please? Sorry for the question.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I don’t think Serre has an accent

If a Dirichlet series $D(s) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n^s}$ converges in some $s_0 \in \mathbb{C}$, then it converges uniformly in every sector $S_\alpha := \{s \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ \text{Re}(s-s_0) \geq 0, \ |\arg(s-s_0)| \leq \alpha\}$ with $0 \leq \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$. As a uniform limit on compact subsets of holomorphic functions is holomorphic, the function $D: \{s \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ \text{Re}(s) > \text{Re}(s_0) \} \to \mathbb{C}, s\mapsto D(s)$ is holomorphic, because every compact subset $C$ of $\{s \in \mathbb{C} \ | \ \text{Re}(s) > \text{Re}(s_0) \}$ is contained in some sector $S_\alpha$ for some $0\leq \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I almost understood. Sorry for the question but, if so, then why did he say "$\zeta_m$ would be holomorphic at $s=1$" before the holomorphicity at $Re(s)>0,$ as an implication? By what you said, why is the convergence at $Re(s)>0$ not enough?

Well, by what I said $L(s,\chi)$ is holomorphic on ${\text{Re}(s) > 0}$ for $\chi \neq \chi_0$. By proposition 11 $L(s,\chi_0)$ is holomorphic on ${\text{Re}(s) > 0}\setminus {1}$ and has a pole of order $1$ in $1$. This pole is cancelled by the hypothetic zero of $L(s,\chi)$ for some $\chi \neq \chi_0$ in $s$, so $\zeta_m$ would be holomorphic on the whole ${\text{Re}(s) > 0}$.
